# Reihenfolge der Satzglieder in einer Frage

Tags: word-order, question

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl wären sowohl

> Gehört das Buch dir?

und

> Gehört dir das Buch?

korrekte Fragen. Laut [diesem Link](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/satzbau) wäre aber nur das erste korrekter Satzbau. Ist das zweite dann eine zulässige Variante/Dialekt?

[Edit] zur Klarstellung: Interessant wäre zu wissen, nach welcher Regel o.ä. allgemeine Konstruktionen der zweiten Form als korrekt gelten.

Comment: Ich stimme Deinem Sprachgefühl zu...

Comment: Beide Fragen sind absolut korrekt. Meinem Gefühl nach darf das Objekt auch vor dem Subjekt kommen, wenn es sich um ein Dativ-Objekt handelt.

Comment: @tofro Was ist mit "Gibst ihm du den Apfel?"? Das klingt wiederum falsch für mich.

Comment: @senegrom, das ist auch falsch. Richtig ist: "Gibst du ihm den Apfel?"

Comment: Meine ich ja. Aber nach der Dativobjektregel von @tofro wäre es fälschlicherweise richtig.

Comment: Beide Sätze sind völlig korrekt!

Comment: @pp_ Es heißt trotzdem *Gibst du ihm.*, egal wie der folgende Satz lautet. *Gibst ihm du…* ist grundsätzlich falsch. Wenn du *ihm* vorziehen willst, dann darf das Pronomen nicht das Subjekt sein. Das Subjekt darf direkt nach dem Verb oder am Ende des Satzes stehen, aber nicht mittendrin.

Comment: @JanekBevendorff Nein, es ist nicht *grundsätzlich* falsch. Es ist nur auf eine seltsame Art betont. Das Subjekt darf im Deutschen, wie jedes Satzglied, an jeder Stelle außer der zweiten stehen (die ist für das finite Verb reserviert).

Comment: @Jan doch, es ist falsch. Man kann Wörter im Satz häufig an den Anfang ziehen, aber nicht einfach irgendwohin schieben. Das Verb steht außerdem nur in Aussagesätzen an zweiter Stelle, wir haben hier aber einen Fragesatz. In einem Fragesatz steht das Subjekt an zweiter Stelle und das Verb an erster ("Gibst (V) du (S) ihm (O)..."). Du kannst hier nicht einfach das Objekt zwischen Verb und Subjekt ziehen.

Answer (score 8):

Für mich hören sich auch beide Fragen korrekt an. Eine Änderung der Reihenfolge zieht jedoch meist auch eine Veränderung der Betonung nach sich, wie hier deutlich wird:

> Gehört das Buch dir? Oder jemandem anderen?
>
> Gehört dir das Buch? Oder hast du es dir nur ausgeliehen?

Comment: *Gehört dir das Buch? Oder doch der Hefter?* wäre auch noch eine Interpretationsmöglichkeit, die bei der anderen Satzstellung nicht aufkommt.